# Is it possible to use a subfolder for github reusable worklow?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm going to create a reusable ("called") GitHub workflow and would like to store it in a separate folder, for example, ".github/workflows/public" but got an error "Missing the full path for reusable workflow" in a caller workflow file. Is it the restriction of GitHub to store workflows only in ".github/workflows" folder?

Comment: Please show your workflow and how you're calling it (YAML snippets)

Answer (score 14):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#creating-a-reusable-workflow)

> Reusable workflows are YAML-formatted files, very similar to any other workflow file. As with other workflow files, you locate reusable workflows in the `.github/workflows` directory of a repository. **Subdirectories of the workflows directory are not supported.**

So the answer to your question is **no**, it's not possible.

Comment: Not possible, yet. Some upvotes may change that ... [REQUEST] Workflows seen in Actions UI separated by folder structure [#11831](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11831); 
Feature request: allow workflow configuration in sub-folders [#18055](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/18055)